# Angular 6: Dropdown display option base on other dropdown value

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have 2 dropdowns, one to select *state* and the other for *service agency*. The options displayed for *service agency* depends on the *state* selected value.

Data for *service agency* and *state* dropdowns are get from `profile.service.ts`.

**Problem:** How I can make the value display in service agency change when user select state.

**profile.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Service Agency" required formControlName="serviceAgency">
        <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="{{item.id}}" *ngFor="let item of service_agency$">                     
            {{item.name}}  
        </mat-option>  
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**profile.component.ts**

```js
//get state
get_state(){
    this.profileService.get_state().subscribe(data => {  
        this.state$ = data; 
    });  
}

//get service center base on state id
onChange(state) {
   this.service_agency$ = this.profileService.get_service_agency()
       .pipe(filter((item)=> item == state.value));

    console.log(this.service_agency$);
}
```

**profile.service.ts**

```js
get_state() {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .pipe(map(data => {
            return data;
        }));
}

get_service_agency() {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .pipe(map(data => {
            return data;
        }));
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: use `async` pipe to auto subscribe.

Comment: @AmitChigadani when I select state, I do not know how to display the dropdown service agency base on the state_id

Comment: @Pengyy I do not understand async pipe work can you explain more

Comment: @Firdaus refer demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdxdkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html   For docs, see https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

In angular , when you update any data it will reflect that data in html also.

I guess when you change the value of state , You call the API and fetch the new list of `service agency`.

When you get the new list just you have to bind that new list into variable. Angular will bind that new list into html automatically.

```
<option *ngFor="let item of service_agency$" value=[item.name]>
    {{item.name}}        
</option>
```

When change the state value :

```
onChange(state) {  // Get the ref of selected state 

  // Now hear you need to call API and pass state id and get new list of agency
  this.profileService.get_service_agency().subscribe((data) => {            

         // Clear all data from array and then bind new fresh data 
        this.service_agency$ = [];             // Clear 
        this.service_agency$.push(...data);    // Bind fresh data

        // Check data is bind in array properly or not ... 
        console.log("New service list data is ::: " , this.service_agency$);

  })
}
```

After bind a fresh data , new list will automatically display in `HTML` page.